# Ansible Xen Provisioning

Tags: ansible, provisioning, xen

I started with Ansible yesterday and try to provision VM's on my private XenServer.

I followed this Guide:
[XenGuide Sharknet.us](https://sharknet.us/2013/12/13/276/)

So I can reache the Xen Server with a ping from ansible.

My Project folder has the following Structure:

```
Project Folder
|-- site.yml
|-- hosts (inventory file)
+-+ host_vars
| |-- master01.lab.local
| |-- master02.lab.local
| |-- slave01.lab.local
| |-- slave02.lab.local
+-+ group_vars
| |-- all
+-+ roles
| +-+ master
| | |-- main.yml
| +-+ slave
| | |-- main.yml
| +-+ vm
| | |-- create_vm.yml
| | |-- main.yml
```

My file Site.yml:

```
[vm]
master01.lab.local
master02.lab.local
slave01.lab.local
slave02.lab.local

[hypervisor]
xen01.lab.local
```

host_vars/master01.lab.local as example:

```
hostname: master01
ram: 8GiB
vcpus: 4
```

groups_vars/all file:

```
centos_template_uid: 11fd3dc9-96cc-49af-b091-a2ca7e94c589
primary_sr_uid: 6e074a6e-bf19-031d-7c65-c9ab2749a3da
user_network_uid: 087af565-bd27-cd0a-93e4-724beeb27735
```

roles/vm/main.yml

```
 - name: Check if VM exists
   command: xe vm-list name-label={{ hostname }}
   register: found
   delegate_to: xen01.lab.local

 - include: create_vm.yml
   when: found.stdout == ""

 - name: Wait for the Kickstart install to complete and the VM to reboot
   local_action: wait_for host={{ hostname }}.lab.local port=22 delay=15 timeout=1200 state=started
```

roles/vm/create_vm.yml

```
- name: Prevent template from creating storage
  command: xe template-param-remove uuid={{ centos_template_uid }} param-name=other-config param-key=disks
  ignore_errors: yes
  delegate_to: xen01.lab.loca

- name: Create VM
  command: xe vm-install template={{ centos_template_uid }} new-name-label="{{ hostname }}" sr-uuid={{ primary_sr_uid }}
  register: vm
  delegate_to: xen01.lab.local

- name: Set the repository location
  command: xe vm-param-set uuid={{ vm.stdout }} other-config:install-repository="http://ansible-repo.lab.local/"
  delegate_to: xen01.lab.local

- name: Set the location of the kickstart file
  command: xe vm-param-set uuid={{ vm.stdout }} PV-args="ks=http://ansible-repo.lab.local/ks.cfg ksdevice=eth0"
  delegate_to: xen01.lab.local

- name: Assign a network
  command: xe vif-create vm-uuid={{ vm.stdout }} network-uuid={{ user_network_uid }} mac={{ mac }} device=0
  delegate_to: xen01.lab.local

- name: Allocate VM storage
  command: xe vdi-create name-label="{{ hostname }} storage" sr-uuid={{ primary_sr_uid }} type=system virtual-size=25GiB
  register: disk
  delegate_to: xen01.lab.local

- name: Assign storage to VM
command: xe vbd-create vdi-uuid={{ disk.stdout }} vm-uuid={{ vm.stdout }} type=Disk bootable=true device=0
delegate_to: xen01.lab.local

- name: Set the VM RAM limits
  command: xe vm-memory-limits-set vm={{ vm.stdout }} static-min={{ ram }} static-max={{ ram }} dynamic-min={{ ram }} dynamic-max={{ ram }}
  delegate_to: xen01.lab.local

- name: Set the number of CPUs
  command: xe vm-param-set VCPUs-max={{ vcpus }} uuid={{ vm.stdout }}
  delegate_to: xen01.lab.local

- name: Launch the VM
  command: xe vm-start uuid={{ vm.stdout }}
  delegate_to: xen01.lab.local
```

If i run now the following command:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts site.yml -K
```

i get the following error:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.

The error appears to have been in '/var/ansible/ansible-playbooks/provisioning/xen/roles/vm/tasks/main.yml': line 2, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:
- name: Check if VM exists
  command: xe vm-list name-label={{ hostname }}
^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

with_items:
  - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

with_items:
  - "{{ foo }}"
```

Does somebody know this error?

Answer (score 0):

You should quote strings, containing variables, so in you case

```
command: xe vm-list name-label={{ hostname }}
```

should become

```
command: xe vm-list name-label="{{ hostname }}"
```

Same applies to all other tasks without quotes around variables